# Tags artificial-consciousness and self-awareness should be merged

Tags: discussion, tags

The only difference between [artificial-consciousness](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-consciousness) and [self-awareness](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-awareness) is that the former is "restricted to engineered artifacts", so I think these tags should be merged and only the tag [artificial-consciousness](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-consciousness) should exist, given that "restricted to engineered artifacts" does not deserve its own tag on a website related to the theoretical and philosophical aspects of AI.

Answer (score 1):

Self-awareness has a lot of usage in general, and I don't think it's entirely synonymous.  Consciousness, in the most basic definition, is merely awareness of an environment.

Additionally, non-artificial intelligences (humans) have self-awareness.  So it's useful to be able to distinguish.

Comment: How is awareness different from consciousness? AFAIK, they are synonymous. My point is that there is no need to introduce a tag for every single detail. The expression "artificial consciousness" already covers (artificial) awareness. In a site dedicated to AI, there should be no need to just talk about non-artificial awareness or consciousness, that is, the discussion should be related to artificial intelligence in some way. Furthermore, in the context of AI, artificial consciousness is a more common expression. I really don't see the need to introduce two extremely similar tags.

Comment: @nbro awareness is synonymous with consciousness, but *self-awareness* is a qualified form of awareness.  (This goes back to at least the Delphic maxim "know thyself", although that is typically understood in the sense of Thoreau--the "examined life".)  My sense is that self-awareness has a lot of use in the literature.

Comment: Ok, but I think that artificial consciousness also includes all discussions related to consciousness including artificial self-consciousness or artificial self-awareness. Maybe we could rename the tag [tag:artificial-consciousness] and make it just [tag:consciousness] (in the same way that we have the tag [tag:attention] rather than [tag:artificial-attention]), but I don't think this is necessary. I would say that "self" is even redundant, given that "consciousness" is all about being aware of something, including yourself.

Comment: It's just that there does seem to be some basis for asking about the parallel concepts in the natural work, so consciousness in general is distinct from artificial consciousness.  (For instance, questions about Penrose's theory of mind in relation to humans, which would be on-topic, even where it didn't get into AI.)

Comment: Ok, then I would suggest having just the tag [tag:consciousness], which should cover both artificial and natural consciousness. I just think that awareness and consciousness are so similar that people will be confused. Indeed, I would not know which one to use (unless I read the description and even in that case it might be confusing).